# Cauchy's Formula for Repeated Integration - Confusion Re. Bounds

Tags: integration

In the Wikipedia article about this formula, there is included a proof of its validity by induction (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration). In the second-to-last line of the proof, the order of integration is reversed and the bounds take a rather dramatic turn in a manner that I cannot fathom:

$ 
    \begin{align} \int_a^x \int_a^{\sigma_1}\left(\sigma_1-t\right)^{n-1} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}\sigma_1 = \int_a^x \int_t^x\left(\sigma_1-t\right)^{n-1} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma_1\,\mathrm{d}t \end{align}    $

Having tried this identity for a couple special cases, I've managed to 'convince' myself (for the time being) that it works, and I can (vaguely) see why - we're just rearranging dummy variables and constants to ensure that we end up with the desired antiderivative in terms of $x$ w.r.t. the basepoint $a$ - but I'm still completely in the dark as to why, precisely, we are allowed to reshuffle the bounds in this fashion.

After all, this is really just a definite integral subject to the results of Fubini's Theorem. But I cannot readily envision the space(s) over which we are integrating since we're working with no fewer than three (3) parameters/dummy variables, along with a single constant $a$, all of which appear at various junctures within the integrand. It almost looks as though we begin by integrating over a 'rectangle' with two variable bounds, then switch to a triangle of some sort, but I'm uncertain. Can anyone weigh in here? All apologies if my question is too verbose, incoherent, boring, and/or meaningless - I'm new around here.

Comment: It's always a triangle. In the case $x > a$, it's the triangle $\{(\sigma_1,\, t) : a \leqslant t \leqslant \sigma_1 \leqslant x\}$, with the vertices $(a,a),\, (x,a),\, (x,x)$.

Comment: Well, alright, I suppose. But that's hardly obvious to me. Since $a$ is merely some fixed real value, I presumed that on the left-hand side, we were integrating over $\{ (\sigma_1 , t) : a \le \sigma_1\le x ,\,\, a \le t \le \sigma_1 \}$, which is clearly a rectangle, provided that $a$ is free to appear on both axes (I see no reason why this couldn't or wouldn't be so). Are these two regions equivalent as bounds for our integral, or am I misinterpreting the nature of the problem? Further, why is $t$ constrained to be less than or equal to our other parameters?

Comment: It's not a rectangle. The interval for the integration with respect to $t$ depends on $\sigma_1$, and what you get is a triangle. It's probably a little easier to not get confused if we remove $a$, and replace all occurrences of $a$ with $0$.

Comment: Okay, that makes quite a bit of sense. As you can see, I probably need to brush up on my regions of integration. Thanks for clearing all this up.